# I can get batch file to open non-default browser but browser won't go to website

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a batch file to open a bunch of programs at once.  I have to open two browsers for sites that only work in specific browsers (My work is weird).

I need to open chrome, which is non default, that is located on a network server. I can get it to open the browser with the following code but it will not go to the website.  I don't know why.

`START "" /d "\\server\path\folder" "\\server\path\folder\file.exe" "http://google.com"`

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window and run there `start /?`. You get displayed the help for this command.

You will read `[/Dpath]`. There is no space between parameter `/D` and the path of start directory.

However, browsers don't require that the start directory is equal the program files directory of the browser.

I suggest to omit the start directory:

```
start "Open Google in Chrome" "\\Server\Share\Path to Chrome\chrome.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
```